# Combining output of two queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite, sql-server-2008

table1:

```
col1   col2
john   new york
jimmy  london
jerry  mumbai
jack   perth
```

table2:

```
col1   col3
john   10
jimmy  20
jerry  40
jack   30
```

Query 1 is

```
select col1,col2 from table1
```

Query 2 is

```
select col1,col3 from table2
```

now since col1 of both the queries are same, I want to merge both the queries and require following o/p

```
col1   col2        col3
john   new York    10
jimmy  London      20
jerry  Mumbai      40
jack   perth       30
```

thanks.

Comment: Tip of today: Do a JOIN!

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
SELECT t1.col1
    ,t1.col2
    ,t2.col3
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.col1 = t2.col1
```